# How do I make a uber-simple API wrapper in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, api

I'm trying to use a super simple [API](http://is.gd/api_info.php) from is.gd:

```
http://is.gd/api.php?longurl=http://www.example.com
```

Which returns a response header "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" if the URL was shortened as expected, or "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" if there was any problem that prevented this. Assuming the request was successful, the body of the response will contain only the new shortened URL

I don't even know where to begin or if there are any available ruby methods to make sending and receiving of these API requests frictionless. I basically want to assign the response (the shortened url) to a ruby object.

How would you do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Super simple:

```
require 'open-uri'

def shorten(url)
  open("http://is.gd/api.php?longurl=#{url}").read
rescue
  nil
end
```

`open-uri` is part of the Ruby standard library and (among other things) makes it possible to do HTTP requests using the `open` method (which usually opens files). `open` returns an IO, and calling `read` on the IO returns the body. `open-uri` will throw an exception if the server returns a 500 error, and in this case I'm catching the exception and return `nil`, but if you want you can let the exception bubble up to the caller, or raise another exception.

Oh, and you would use it like this:

```
url = "http://www.example.com"
puts "The short version of #{url} is #{shorten(url)}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you already got an answer you accepted, but I still want to mention [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) because I've made very good experiences wrapping APIs (Delicious and Github) with it.